# How do I use 'whois' on cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I've just installed the *whois* package on cygwin. Its description is *GNU Whois*, I'm assuming it refers to [jwhois](http://www.gnu.org/software/jwhois/)? I'm thinking the package is completely broken, but just in case I'm doing something wrong, here are some input and output results:

```
$ whois
Usage: whois [OPTION]... OBJECT...
[rest of help here]

$ whois superuser.com
connect: Connection timed out

$ whois --help
whois: unknown option -- -
Usage: whois [OPTION]... OBJECT...
[rest of help here]

$ whois --version
whois: unknown option -- -
Usage: whois [OPTION]... OBJECT...
[rest of help here]
```

So, is this package broken or am I not using it correctly?

Comment: Your syntax looks good. Can you ping superuser.com?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Yeah, that works fine. superuser.com was just an example, I get the same output for every domain. So I guess the package is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like whois is failing to connect to the server to fetch the information needed. You can specify WHOIS_SERVER to use another server than the default one.

Try the following:

```
> env WHOIS_SERVER=whois.ripe.net whois superuser.com
```

or

```
> whois -h whois.ripe.net superuser.com
```

You can check if your internet connection can connect to a WHOIS service with any telnet client:

```
> telnet whois.ripe.net 43
Trying 193.0.6.135...
Connected to whois.ripe.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
% This is the RIPE Database query service.
% The objects are in RPSL format.
%
% The RIPE Database is subject to Terms and Conditions.
% See http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf
```

Comment: I had forgotten about this issue. Apparently port 43 is blocked at this company's network, telnet is unable to connect.

Comment: How do you check for what is your existing whois server in CygWin?